# progress bar change back ground when clicked and change back

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG1ZE0NJ4ZX7

[image]

I made a progress bar that looks like the screenshot
and it turns to green when I hover on it.
I want to make make the bg-color changed to green
and change it back to white when I click another bar.
Please help!

Comment: This can be done by JavaScript, add a special class to the element you want to have a different background-color, and remove that class from all other elements (let's say that class name is ".clicked")

Comment: This will help you: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use jquery, add click event to all `<a>` under element with class `breadcrumb`:

```
$('.breadcrumb > a').on('click', function() {
  $('.breadcrumb > a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Use CSS rule `active`, when a tab clicked, remove all active then add class `active` to the one you just clicked.

```js
$('.breadcrumb > a').on('click', function() {
  $('.breadcrumb > a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: #444
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .breadcrumb {
      /*centering*/
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 5px;
      /*Lets add the numbers for each link using CSS counters. flag is the name of the counter. to be defined using counter-reset in the parent element of the links*/
      counter-reset: flag;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .breadcrumb a {
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      line-height: 36px;
      color: white;
      /*need more margin on the left of links to accomodate the numbers*/
      padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
      background: #666;
      background: linear-gradient(#666, #333);
      position: relative;
    }
    /*since the first link does not have a triangle before it we can reduce the left padding to make it look consistent with other links*/
    
    .breadcrumb a:first-child {
      padding-left: 46px;
    }
    
    .breadcrumb a:first-child:before {
      left: 14px;
    }
    
    .breadcrumb a:last-child {
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    /*hover/active styles*/
    
    .breadcrumb a.active,
    .breadcrumb a:hover {
      background: #333;
      background: linear-gradient(#333, #000);
    }
    
    .breadcrumb a.active:after,
    .breadcrumb a:hover:after {
      background: #333;
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, #333, #000);
    }
    /*adding the arrows for the breadcrumbs using rotated pseudo elements*/
    
    .breadcrumb a:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -18px;
      /*half of square's length*/
      /*same dimension as the line-height of .breadcrumb a */
      width: 36px;
      height: 36px;
      transform: scale(0.707) rotate(45deg);
      /*we need to prevent the arrows from getting buried under the next link*/
      z-index: 1;
      /*background same as links but the gradient will be rotated to compensate with the transform applied*/
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, #666, #333);
      /*stylish arrow design using box shadow*/
      box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 3px -3px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      border-radius: 0 5px 0 50px;
    }
    /*we dont need an arrow after the last link*/
    
    .breadcrumb a:last-child:after {
      content: none;
    }
    /*we will use the :before element to show numbers*/
    
    .breadcrumb a:before {
      /*some styles now*/
      border-radius: 100%;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 30px;
      background: #444;
      background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .flat a,
    .flat a:after {
      background: white;
      color: black;
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    
    .flat a:hover,
    .flat a.active,
    .flat a:hover:after,
    .flat a.active:after {
      color: white;
      background: #369F00;
    }
    
    .flat input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
      background: #369F00;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="breadcrumb flat">
        <a href="#">
                                        Invite a New Applicant
                                    </a>
        <a href="#">
          <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" value="new" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter" class="" name="ko_unique_9"> New Applicants (
              <span data-bind="text: newApplicationsCount">4</span>)
            </label>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" value="shortlisted" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter" name="ko_unique_10"> Shortlisted Applicants (
              <span data-bind="text: shortlistedApplicationsCount">0</span>)
            </label>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" value="connected" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter" name="ko_unique_11"> Connected Applicants (
              <span data-bind="text: connectedApplicationsCount">0</span>)
            </label>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="breadcrumb flat">
        <a href="#">
                                        <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="visible: applications().length > 0">
                                            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showHiddenApplications">
                                            Hidden
                                        </label>
                                    </a>
      </div>





    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```